How to convert to dict for append action?
Having something like this:
>>> import argparse
>>> ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> ap.add_argument('-e', '--env', action='append', nargs=2, metavar=('NAME', 'VALUE'), dest='extra_env', help='set some env var to given value')
_AppendAction(option_strings=['-e', '--env'], dest='extra_env', nargs=2, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='set some env var to given value', metavar=('NAME', 'VALUE'))

it kind of works:
>>> ap.parse_args(['-e', 'SOMEENVVAR', 'SOMEVAL', '--env', 'OTHERENVVAR', 'OTHERVAL'])
Namespace(extra_env=[['SOMEENVVAR', 'SOMEVAL'], ['OTHERENVVAR', 'OTHERVAL']])

but I was wondering how to instantly transform this into a dict? Now I have to do this in some postprocessing:
>>> args = ap.parse_args(['-e', 'SOMEENVVAR', 'SOMEVAL', '--env', 'OTHERENVVAR', 'OTHERVAL'])
>>> dict(args.extra_env)
{'SOMEENVVAR': 'SOMEVAL', 'OTHERENVVAR': 'OTHERVAL'}

I wanted to use the type argument for that, but it seems that the combination of action=append and nargs=2 seems to break it; the function passed to type is called for each of the args in nargs individually:
>>> ap.add_argument('-e', '--env', action='append', nargs=2, metavar=('NAME', 'VALUE'), dest='extra_env', help='set some env var to given value', type=lambda x: print(f'called lambda for >{x}<'))
_AppendAction(option_strings=['-e', '--env'], dest='extra_env', nargs=2, const=None, default=None, type=<function <lambda> at 0x7f904df518c8>, choices=None, help='set some env var to given value', metavar=('NAME', 'VALUE'))
>>> ap.parse_known_args(['-e', 'SOMEENVVAR','SOMEVAL', '--env', 'OTHERENVVAR','OTHERVAL'])
called lambda for >SOMEENVVAR<
called lambda for >SOMEVAL<
called lambda for >OTHERENVVAR<
called lambda for >OTHERVAL<
(Namespace(extra_env=[[None, None], [None, None]]), [])


If you actually look at what the type is called with, it should be clear that what you have is about the best approach you're likely to get.

@jonrsharpe checked it already - see the updated question

Ok, not much we can add then!

type gets an individual string, not all the strings specified by nargs.  A custom action subclass could do the job. But given how simple the post parsing step is, is it necessary?

The type argument is passed to each input before the action is applied.  Instead, you can pass a custom action that will create a dictionary from your pairs of values.
class DictAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        args_dict = getattr(namespace, self.dest, None) or {}
        args_dict.update(dict([values]))
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, args_dict)

ap.add_argument(
    '-e', '--env', 
    action=DictAction, 
    nargs=2, 
    metavar=('NAME', 'VALUE'), 
    dest='extra_env', 
    help='set some env var to given value',
)

Here is the output:
ap.parse_args(['-e', 'SOMEENVVAR', 'SOMEVAL', '--env', 'OTHERENVVAR', 'OTHERVAL'])
# returns:
Namespace(extra_env={'SOMEENVVAR': 'SOMEVAL', 'OTHERENVVAR': 'OTHERVAL'})


Ninja edited to remove the type argument.
